# How we can define a State variable type Any?

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Update: This Method is just for learning Goal not using in real project!(Until new update)**

Here I do get 2 issue with defining a State var as `Any` type. As you know, we have to initialize it. For example in this code I have to initialize my State var with Image, which is not I want, the all point of choosing any as type was freedom of feeding the type, but State take this freedom from me with initialize it, and cherry on top, I have to force unwrapping for State to became usable for it!

So with this 2 issue (initialize+force unwrapping) about var type any with State, do we have ways to solve those issues?

```
@State var anyItem: Any = UIImage(named: "apple")!
```

**Here my New Update of code with help of master's:**

```
   import SwiftUI
    
    struct ContentView: View
    {
    
    @State var anyItem: Any?
    @State var changedType: Bool = false
    
    init() {
        _anyItem = .init(initialValue: UIImage(named: "Apple"))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if changedType == false
        {
            Image(uiImage: anyItem as! UIImage)
        }
        else
        {
            Text(anyItem as! String)
        }
        
        Text("Test")
            .onTapGesture
            {
                chandType.toggle()
                anyItem = "anyItem changed to Text! Kaboom!"
            }
    }
}
```

**V2: Advanced Version**

```
   import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View
    {
    @State var anyItem: Any?
    enum anyItemType { case String, Image, Unknowen }
    @State var choosenType: anyItemType = anyItemType.Unknowen

    var body: some View {

        
        ZStack
        {
            
            VStack
            {
                if choosenType == anyItemType.String
                {
                    Text(anyItem as! String).bold()
                }
                else if choosenType == anyItemType.Image
                {
                    Image(uiImage: anyItem as! UIImage).resizable().frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center).clipShape(Circle())
                }
            }
            
            
            VStack
            {
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(choosenType == anyItemType.String ? "Change anyItem Type to Image" : "Change anyItem Type to String")
                {
                    
                    if choosenType == anyItemType.String
                    {
                        anyItem = UIImage(named: "Apple")
                        choosenType = anyItemType.Image
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        anyItem = "anyItem changed to Text! KABOOOM!"
                        choosenType = anyItemType.String
                    }
                }.font(Font.body.bold())
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 100)
   
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what do you try to achieve here... anywhere assigning something to Any variable you lost real type and would need to restore it later by `is` or `as`. Actually it is bad design for swift - use either static types or generics, otherwise you'll got into troubles, sooner or later but definitely.

Comment: yes you are right, I would never use State with type of Any! it is asking for trouble! crash crash crash! LoL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't because of `Any`. It's because this line:

```
UIImage(named: "apple")
```

returns an *optional* (`UIImage?`).

---

If you want `anyItem` to accept values of type `UIImage?` you need to make it `Any?`:

```
@State var anyItem: Any? = UIImage(named: "apple")
```

or provide a default value for the optional:

```
@State var anyItem: Any = UIImage(named: "apple") ?? UIImage()
```

---

Here is an example of how you can init `anyItem` with different *types* (this is just for demo and probably shouldn't be used in a *real* application):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var anyItem: Any?
    
    init() {
        _anyItem = .init(initialValue: UIImage(named: "apple"))
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .onAppear {
                anyItem = "test"
            }
    }
}
```

But as Asperi has already suggested, it's not a good idea and you generally want to avoid using `Any` in SwiftUI.

Comment: Well you salved half the problem about unwrapping! But Another half of the issue exists and that is about initializing issue, the reason of choosing Any for me is to get freedom of  choosing the type, with my or your code, at the first step losing this freedom. Look at this code ***var anyItem: Any?***  we can do anything with that later on in our codes! But with your code we will limit ourself just for Image, for example I will not be able to sign String or URL to anyItem, so this half of issue still there.

Comment: @Omid You will be able to assign different types. See the updated answer. But please consider different approaches as mentioned in the comments.